How to verify (or proof) the following results of maximization and minimization problems?
As an engineer who is currently studying optimization, I am currently having trouble solving the following problems:
$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\left( {{P_1}} \right)}&{\min }&{{{\log }_2}\left( {1 + \frac{x}{y}} \right)}\\
{}&{}&{a \le x \le b}\\
{}&{}&{c \le y \le d}
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\left( {{P_2}} \right)}&{\max }&{{{\log }_2}\left( {1 + \frac{x}{y}} \right)}\\
{}&{}&{a \le x \le b}\\
{}&{}&{c \le y \le d}
\end{array}$
Here $x,y,a,b,c,d$ are all non negative since they are physical quantities in the real world.
One of my friend give me an answer using software and currently I do not know if this answer is correct or not
For problem $(P_1)$ the minimimum value is $\frac{{\ln \left( {1 + \frac{a}{d}} \right)}}{{\ln \left( 2 \right)}}$ when $x=a$ and $y=d$
For problem $(P_2)$ the maximum value is $\frac{{\ln \left( {1 + \frac{b}{c}} \right)}}{{\ln \left( 2 \right)}}$ when $x=b$ and $y=c$
Please help me with this, thank you for your enthusiasm !

Remark: $c$ should be positive since $y$ appears in the denominator.
If $a \le x \le b$ and $c \le y \le d$, then we have
$a \le x \le b$ and $\frac1d \le \frac1y \le \frac1c$ and hence
$$\frac{a}{d}\le \frac{x}{y}\le \frac{b}{c}$$
where $\frac{a}{d}$ is attained when $x=a$ and $y=d$ and $\frac{c}{d} $ is attained when $x=b$ and $y=c$.
Note that $\log_2(1+z)$ is an increasing function of $z$ and hence the result holds.

Wow this is very fast and intuitive but is there a KKT proof for this problem ?

Draft: Suppose $a<x<b$, from $\lambda_1 (x-b)=0$ and $\mu(a-x)=0$, then the langrange multiplier are equal to $0$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$, but we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}>0$ which is a contradiciton. By this argument, the extrema are obtained at the corner, enumerate them and you can compare the values.
